# CONCAT() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I need an output like `500000 (Cr)`, and I tried this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUM(transactioninfo.CreditAmount),'Cr')
   AS creditdAmount FROM transaction;
```

But I'm getting only `500000`.

Table structure:

```
Id CreditAmount DebitAmount Transactiondate
-- ------------ ----------- ---------------
1   100000            0         2015-12-08
2   100000          5000          2015-12-08
3   100000          2000          2015-12-08
4   100000          3000          2015-12-08
5   100000          5000          2015-12-08
```

Comment: show table structure

Comment: Id   CreditAmount  DebitAmount  Transactiondate
--   ------------  -----------  ---------------
1    100000    0   2015-12-08
2    100000    5000  2015-12-08
3    100000    2000  2015-12-08
4    100000    3000  2015-12-08
5    100000    5000  2015-12-08

Comment: try `CONCAT(CONVERT(SUM(transactioninfo.CreditAmount),char),'Cr')`

Comment: Hello transactioninfo.CreditAmount or transaction.creditdAmount??

Comment: transactioninfo.CreditAmount

Comment: what is datatype of CreditAmount

Comment: First its not defined that from where you are getting transactioninfo? because your main table is transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to CAST your value as varchar and then try like this:

```
SELECT  CONCAT(CAST(SUM(transactioninfo.CreditAmount) AS char(20)),' (Cr)') AS creditdAmount FROM transactioninfo;
```

Comment: @AnjuMathew:- Are you getting any error? Also what is the datatype for `transactioninfo.CreditAmount` column? Also you have linked two table in your query 1. transactioninfo 2. transaction.

Comment: Yes. I'm getting syntax error. Sorry, it's actually transactioninfo and the datatype is double

Comment: @AnjuMathew:- Whats the error? Also I have updated the query, assuming the table name as `transactioninfo`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(50)),' (Cr)') AS AmountCredited
 -- (SUM(transactioninfo.CreditA' at line 11

Comment: @AnjuMathew:- Please check the updated query. It should work now! Instead of `varchar` just use `char`

Comment: Yes. But I'm not getting correct answer. Actually I want this select query inside a temporary table and its datatype in temporary table is varchar.

Comment: @AnjuMathew:- In that case you need to add more details to your question. Or better ask a new question in which you can provide details about your question. As per this question you asked for a query and the above does that. It will also help you to attract more people. But do make sure you provide sufficient details to it.

Comment: I got it. I tried this:  CONCAT(CONVERT(SUM(transactioninfo.CreditAmount),CHAR(20)),' (Cr)') AS AmountCredited

Comment: @AnjuMathew:- Yes that will work as well. The point was to convert your `transactioninfo.CreditAmount` column to char

Comment: @SimhachalamGulla:- Yes this will work as you can use CAST or CONVERT anything to convert the datatypes

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following. It will be worth it for you:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(CONVERT(SUM(transactioninfo.CreditAmount), char), ' (Cr)') AS creditdAmount 
FROM transactioninfo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
 SELECT concat(creditdAmount,' (Cr)') FROM  
   (  
    SELECT SUM(id) AS creditdAmount FROM transaction  
   )as temp;
```